# Are all latitudes of $S^2$ closed submanifolds of $S^2$?

Tags: differential-topology

Are all latitudes of $S^2$ closed submanifolds of $S^2$(closed subspace rather than compact)?

I think it should be true, because latitudes can be viewed as $S^1$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean "closed subspace rather than compact" but yes, the (non-degenerate) latitudes of $S^2$ are one-dimensional closed submanifolds diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: And the degenerate latitudes of $S^2$ are zero-dimensional closed submanifolds, diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^0$.  But it's, perhaps, worth pointing out that "can be viewed as $S^1$" does not necessarily give a submanifold.  For example, a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ "can be viewed as $S^1$" in the sense that it is homeomorphic to $S^1$, but it is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.